# Read csv file pandas - filename

Tags: python, pandas, csv, filenames

I am trying to read several csv files that all have different names but same structure inside:

```
u'/1001/download field1.imem_LOG.csv', 
u'/1001/IRDP_01_25_2018_11_47_16.imem_LOG.csv',
u'/1001/IRDP_08_06_2014_15_07_35.imem_LOG.csv',
u'/1001/IRDP_03_17_2014_15_38_03_LOG.csv',
u'/1001/IRDP-KK-1001_09_11_2017_14_40_48.imem_LOG.csv',
```

I cannot read the first and last one:

```
folder = dataiku.Folder("AfbOboIX")



list_files = folder.list_paths_in_partition()
list_files
list_files_split = map(lambda x : x.split("_"),list_files)
list_files_split

list_idx = [list_files_split.index(x) for x in list_files_split if "LOG.csv" in x]list_idx
list_files_log = [list_files[idx] for idx in list_idx]
list_files_log
    output = pd.DataFrame()
    for name in list_files_log:
        with folder.get_download_stream(name) as f:
            try:
                tmp = pd.read_csv(f)
                tmp = tmp.fillna(0)
                output = output.append(tmp)
            except:
                pass
```

`

How can I solve it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What *exactly* is the problem that you face?

Comment: I cannot read them all. Is there an issue with the .csv filename when importing such as "-"

Comment: What does that mean exactly? Do you get an error message? Is your dataframe incomplete? Which of the files cannot be read? In order to help you here you have to be as specific as possible.

Comment: I get a dataframe, the first one and the last one do not appear in the dataframe

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the 'Pass' at the except.
Raise and exception or write the the log the error that occurred.
And then It will be easier to understand what is the problem.

```
import logging
output = pd.DataFrame()
for name in list_files_log:
    with folder.get_download_stream(name) as f:
        try:
            tmp = pd.read_csv(f)
            tmp = tmp.fillna(0)
            output = output.append(tmp)
        except Exception as err:
            logging.error(err.message)
            logging.exception(err)  # Shows the traceback.
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'err'

Comment: ERROR:root:No columns to parse from file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-102-6e0e8c37fd74>", line 6, in <module>
    tmp = pd.read_csv(f)

Comment: File "/home/dss/python.packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 764, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/home/dss/python.packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 985, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/home/dss/python.packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1605, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 565, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas/_libs/parsers.c:6260)
EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file

Comment: Print the name of the file to the log too, logging.info(name), seems like one of the file has invalid content.

Answer (score 1):

> **The new code without [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)**

I think what you want can be solved using Ipython:

```
import pandas as pd

files= !ls *.csv #IPhython stuff
data= pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, enconding='latin1') for f in files], sort=False)
```

Hope it helps.

> **The old code**

I think what you want can be solved using the [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) library:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

dir= 'dir/*.csv'

files = glob.glob(dir)
data= pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in sorted(files)], sort=False)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It tells me that concat is not defined

Comment: still tells me that concat is not defiend

Comment: It tells me then TypeError: concat() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sort

Comment: import glob
import pandas as pd

dir= 'dir/*.csv'

files = glob.glob(dir) # IPython stuff
data= pd.concat([read_csv(f) for f in sorted(files)], sort=False)

Comment: My folder in which I have the csv files is called ''Folder''. Shall I use dir='folder/*.csv'

Comment: @Paul - yeah you can use, or you can use `files=os.listdir('folder')`

Comment: OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'folder'

Comment: @Paul - It means there is a no `folder` in current directory.

Comment: @Paul Put the csv in a folder or use glob as mentioned in the old code

Answer (score 1):

```
import glob

print(glob.glob(path_of_folder+"/*.csv"))
```

and

```
for index,filename in enumerate(glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")):
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(filename))
```

Comment: TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to listpath_of_folder is not defined

Comment: you need to give path of folder as a string, or dir*

Comment: If my folder is called ''folder'', shall I put
print(glob.glob(folder+"/*.csv")) ?

Comment: No you need to give the full path of that folder like in linux, it can be /home/paul/downloads/folder.  And in Windows it will be like c:/downloads/folder

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the files and append them one by one

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

dir = 'path_to_directory/*.csv'

files = glob.glob(dir)

data = pd.DataFrame()

for f in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    data = data.append(df)
```

`data` will contain all the dataframes in the directory